# PHP Desglosar array bidimensional (primera dimension ASOCIATIVA, segunda dimension NUMERICA)

Tags: php, array

Buenos dias compañeros!

Tengo que mostrar por pantalla toda la info de cada Libro (array numerico) con su ISBN (array asociativo) , la verdad que es la primera vez que los toco y no se muy bien por donde tirar, el forEach me da el siguiente error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$libro" in C:\xampp\htdocs\semana3\ejercicio2.php on line 22**

y mi codigo es este:

```
                  //PRIMERA     //SEGUNDA
                 
    $ISBN = array( "891"       => array( 0 => "editorial : Paraninfo <BR>Titulo: Programacion <BR>Autor: Alfonso Jimenez <BR>Año: 2021 <BR>"),
                   "145634612" => array( 1 => "editorial : Santillana <BR> Titulo: Lenguajes <BR> Autor: Marichel <BR> Año:1990 <BR>"),
                   "8678323"   => array( 2 => "editorial : Perezosos <BR> Titulo : Sistemas <BR> Autor: Jose angel <BR> Año:1880 <BR>"), 
                  
                   "98345897"  => array( 0 => "editorial : Señorias <BR> Titulo: FOL <BR> Autor:Antonio <BR> Año: 2022 <BR>"),
                   "321417"    => array( 1 => "editorial : Lineage <BR> Titulo : Enfermeria <BR> Autor: Marta <BR> Año:2014 <BR>"),             
                  
                   "082587"    => array( 0 => "editorial : Pascuales <BR> Titulo:Los altos de GEM <BR> Autor:Maria Robles <BR> Año: 2012 <BR>"),
                   "2737489"   => array( 1 => "editorial : PascualesPASis <BR> Titulo: Los bajos de JOS <BR> Autor: Pepito <BR> Año: 2010 <BR>"),
);
        
    


foreach ($ISBN as $clave_ISBN => $libro){

    echo "$clave_ISBN :  <BR>";

    while (list($clave , $valor) = each $libro){
        echo "$clave = $valor";
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La segunda parte, en el foreach, tienes una función obsoleta each. Podrías repetir el foreach para cada libro:

```
foreach ($ISBN as $clave_ISBN => $libro){
   echo "$clave_ISBN :".PHP_EOL;
   foreach ($libro as $clave => $valor){
        echo "$clave = $valor";
   }
```

Así extraes la información de cada libro.